# Rails Create model with parent relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have two models: `Schedules` and `Result`.

- Schedule `has_one` Result
- Result `belongs_to` Schedule

`Schedules` data will be created first and as matches happen, we will create the `results` for each `schedule`.

[image]

As in the picture above, the `Create` link will take you to a page where you will create the result for the schedule. I will send the `schedule_id` of the schedule for which `Create` button is clicked.

```
<%= link_to "Create",new_result_url(:schedule_id => schedule.id),{:class => 'btn btn-link btn'}%>
```

And in the **Results#New**

```
  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:schedule_id])
    @result = @schedule.build_result
  end
```

And in the View **results/new.html.erb**

This is where I am stuck or dont know how to submit the result form
for the `schedule_id` I selected

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">

<%= form_for(@result) do |f| %>
    <h3>Enter the result</h3>
    <%= f.text_area :result,class:'form-control' %><br />
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, add:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :schedule_id, value: @schedule.id %>
```

This will pass the `id` of the parent `schedule` in with your params. Also, make sure that you `permit` the parameter `schedule_id` in your controller.

Also, to make it easier to pass the `schedule_id` to the `results#new` page, I'd change the `routes` file to this:

```
resources :schedules do
  resources :results
end
```

That way, the route to the `results#new` page is now `new_schedule_result_path(@schedule)`, which you can use in your `link_to`.

Edit:

Also, change your `form_for` to:

```
<%= form_for[@schedule, @result] do |f| %>
```

You would need to have `@schedule` defined in your controller.

Comment: Thank you Ryan and Jon Evans for your prompt answers, really appreciate !!  I will try out and post the results soon !!

Comment: So in the result/new.html.erb, when I submit the form, it says undefined method results_path.. how do I build the form   `<%= form_for @result do |f| %>` ??    or  as its nested i should do some like this   `<%= form_for @schedule.result do |f| %>`  ?? sorry for being so naive in this, I am new to rails.

Comment: Ah, change your `form_for` to: `<%= form_for [@schedule, @result] do |f| %>`. Of course, you should have `@schedule` defined in your controller.

Comment: It worked !! Ryan, Jon you both are my stars today for helping out. I have been scratching my head for few days now. And learned a lot just in this post !! Actually I used combination of both of your answers, But can only mark one as answer  .....

Answer (score 3):

You might want to nest `result` under `schedules`. In your routes:

```
resources :schedules do
  resource :result
end
```

And then your controller could look something like this:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    schedule.create_result(result_params)
  end

  private

  def schedule
    Schedule.find(params[:schedule_id])
  end

  def result_params
    params.require(:result).permit(:result)
  end
end
```

This architects your application to reflect your actual information architecture, and you don't have to worry about passing ids through hidden fields.